# C-code reading a GPIO port directly from a register on an rpi 2b

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, gpio

I am trying to read a GPIO port on a raspberry pi 2B with C by directly reading the register it relates to. I am using the wiringPi library for setup of the GPIO so that is fine but I need the reading to be as fast as possible (one of the main reasons I am using C) so I am trying to get the code to read the register relating to the port because that is much faster as it has no unnecessary wrappers which slow wiringPi down. From what I have seen online it should be possible by doing `GPIO_LEV & (1<<PIN_NUMBER)` but unfortunately I can't seem to find what value I need to set GPIO_LEV to. Basically I was wondering both whether the above code will work when I get the correct number and what number I should put into the constant GPIO_LEV.

EDIT: I am running Raspbian

Comment: Are you running Raspian, or is it bare metal?

Comment: @cleblanc Raspbian, sorry should have specified, will edit

Comment: With Raspian your process will have a virtual memory map so you won't be able to directly access any physical hardware address,  That's what wiringPi is doing for you.  Only the kernel can directly access physical addresses.

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to access the correct part of the virtual memory map (if that is the correct way to put it) then @cleblanc

Comment: I think you'll find that most likely the setup and hold times for your GPIO are the limiting factor rather than being compute bound by the wiringPi library.  AFAIK it's not possible to access a physical address from a user process.  If you still think wiringPi is too slow you can write your own light weight kernel drivers but as I said I think you'll find it's not necessary.